# Is there any command in api reference for python about nfc

Tags: android, python-2.7, sl4a, qpython

I am working on android, i am new to it. i tried all facades in the api reference of android-python. there are commands for bluetooth,wifi,camera.But, there is no command for nfc to check whether it is on or off or anything. i want to know is there any commands like

Comment: Yesterday NFC support was added to qpython

Answer (score 0):

New version has included the NFC Beam Message functions

http://wiki.qpython.org/changelogs/

You can get scripts from http://packages.qpython.org/index.php/qpython-sl4a/